# Magento 2 - How to add new block to admin panel in product page?

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.4

) I'm new to the Magento world and couldn't find a solution, how to add a new block of the Catalog>Products>Edit>Content>Description type, for example, I need the Description2 block in the admin panel on the product editing page? And how to get it on the product page in the store? Or maybe you can give me links where I can find a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All data(e.g. description/price etc) for product are "Attributes" for the product and each product belongs to an "Attribute set"

You can create a new attribute by go to

```
Store > Attributes > Add New Attribute
```

And the assign the new attributes to "Attribute Set" at following page

```
Store > Attributes > Attribute Set
```

In your case,

drag the new created attributes "description_2" to Groups "Content" on relative attributes set